# include 0 in count sql

Tags: sql, count, db2

Suppose I have this table:

```
|MY_TABLE|
| ID_COL |
|   1    |
|   1    |
|   2    |
|   2    |
```

Now I want to do a count query on this table that would include zero results.
When I try to run my query:

```
Select ID_COL,count(ID_COL) 
from   MY_TABLE 
where ID_COL = '1' or ID_COL = '2' or ID_COL = '100' group by ID_COL
```

The result will only be two rows. I want to display 0 for ID_COL = '100'.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

BTW, I am using DB2.

Comment: You should always add a tag to name your dbms (MySQL or Oracle or SQL Server or whatever).

Comment: Note that the COUNT() for ID_COL=100 is not zero; rather it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create a table on the fly to contain a record per ID:

```
select 1 as id_col union all select 2 union all select 100;
```

Then you can select IDs from this table and show the count:

```
select all_ids.id_col, count(my_table.id_col)
from (select 1 as id_col union all select 2 union all select 3) all_ids
left join my_table on my_table.id_col = all_ids.id_col
group by all_ids.id_col;
```

EDIT: Now that you tagged your request with DB2: DB2 needs a dummy table to select one value from. Rather then `select 1` one must write `select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1`. The complete query:

```
select all_ids.id_col, count(my_table.id_col)
from 
(
  select 1 as id_col from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all 
  select 2 from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all 
  select 3 from sysibm.sysdummy1
) all_ids
left join my_table on my_table.id_col = all_ids.id_col
group by all_ids.id_col;
```

Comment: if 3 is not found your query will still return 1 cause it exist in all_ids

Comment: @ah_hau: You are right. I'll edit. Instead of COUNT(\*), I must use COUNT(my_table.id_col) to exclude non-matches from the counting. Thanks.